# Visual studio no option to choose between debug and release

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, properties, release

Hej hej,
I have a solution with multiple projects (vb.net) , 
with some projects I have the optino to choose between the configuration: 
[image]

and in other projects I don't have that option. (I've had the option before).

[image]

Has anyone an idea to show the option again. I can change it in project file (with notepad) but that's not userfriendly :D.

Greetz,

Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the "Show advanced build configurations" option is checked in the

```
Tools | Projects and Solutions | General
```

options dialog.

Comment: Thanks works like a charm, weird thing I had multiple projects in a solution and some of them had the option, but with your solution every project has the option. Thanks ;-)